# How to return a list of frequencies for a certain value in a dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary

So I have a dict, which contains keys corresponding to a list, which contains str. I want to collect all the same values in said list and sum them together. Perhaps my explanation was confusing so I'll provide an example:

```
function_name({'key1':['apple', 'orange'], 'key2':['orange', 'pear'})
>>> {'apple':1, 'orange':2, 'pear':1}
```

How would I create this function? I was thinking of somehow making a for loop like this:

```
count = 0
for fruit in dict_name:
    if food == 'apple'
        count = count + fruit
```

I am still unsure about how to format this especially how to count the values and collect them, thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can un-nest the dict's values and apply a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> 
>>> d = {'key1':['apple', 'orange'], 'key2':['orange', 'pear']}
>>> Counter(v for sub in d.values() for v in sub)
Counter({'apple': 1, 'orange': 2, 'pear': 1})
```

If you don't like the nested generator comprehension, the un-nesting can be done with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable).

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.values()))
Counter({'apple': 1, 'orange': 2, 'pear': 1})
```

Without imports and with traditional loops, it would look like this:

```
>>> result = {}
>>> for sub in d.values():
...:    for v in sub:
...:        result[v] = result.get(v, 0) + 1
...:        
>>> result
{'apple': 1, 'orange': 2, 'pear': 1}
```

Comment: is it proper form to have more than 1 for loop?

Comment: @EmmaPascoe sure

Comment: thank you so much it has worked! Could I ask what the (v, 0) portion represents?

Comment: @EmmaPascoe `result.get(v, 0)` is saying: give me `result[v]` or `0` if `v` is not in `result`.

Comment: I see, so is this a dict method?

Comment: @EmmaPascoe yes, you can find an explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey).

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counts = Counter([item for sublist in your_dict.values() for item in sublist])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to import any libraries you can do as follows:

```
function_name = {'key1':['apple', 'orange'], 'key2':['orange', 'pear']}
foobar = {}
for key, value in function_name.items():
    for element in value:
        if element in foobar:
            foobar[element] += 1
        else:
            foobar[element] = 1
print(foobar)
```

You check if the value is already in the created dict 'foobar'. If it is you add its value by one. If its not, then you add the value as a key and define its value as one. :)

Comment: Instead of `if element in foobar:` I suggest you consider using the dictionary's  [`setdefault()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method which wouldn't require a library `import` and would allow the the code inside of the inner `for` loop to be reduced to one unconditional statement.

Comment: Yeah, I agree! I just wanted to make it as easy to understand for people who are new to dictionaries. And felt the way I did it was the way OP wanted to do :)

Comment: @martineau how would you use `setdefault` here? Isn't it more of a use case for `get`?

Comment: @timgeb: `get()` could also be used. I was thinking of `foobar[element] = foobar.setdefault(element, 0) + 1`—although admittedly `foobar[element] = foobar.get(element, 0) + 1` would be slightly more concise.

Comment: @martineau Yeah, from my experience `setdefault` is most useful when the dict should have mutable values, e.g. `d.setdefault(k, []).append(1)` (without an assignment).

Comment: @timgeb: Good point—either way, the primary point of my comment is that the built-in `dict` class has methods what could be used to simplify the "no `import`" approach being proposed in this answer.